# python list reverse and merge

Tags: python, tuples, reverse

I have these two lists

```
a = [(0,1), (1,2), (3,4)]
b = [[(0,1), (6,7), (8,9)], [(4,5), (7,15), (20,25)], [(18,17), (3,4)]]
```

what i need is check if the first tuple in a exists in b then merge its reverse
so expected output is

```
ab = [[(3,4),(1,2),(0,1),(6,7), (8,9)], [(4,5), (7,15), (20,25)], [(18,17),(3,4)]]
```

my sample code is:

```
import copy
ab = copy.deepcopy(b)

for coord in b:
    if a[0] in coord:
        #print "Yes", coord.index(a[0])
        ab.insert(coord.index(a[0]), a[::-1])

print ab
```

But it doesn't give me the output i want. Anybody out there who can help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to rebuild `b`:

```
ab = [a[:0:-1] + sub if a[0] in sub else sub for sub in b]
```

The `a[:0:-1]` slice not only reverses `a`, it also excludes the first element of `a` to prevent duplicates in the output:

```
>>> a = [(0,1), (1,2), (3,4)]
>>> b = [[(0,1), (6,7), (8,9)], [(4,5), (7,15), (20,25)], [(18,17), (3,4)]]
>>> [a[:0:-1] + sub if a[0] in sub else sub for sub in b]
[[(3, 4), (1, 2), (0, 1), (6, 7), (8, 9)], [(4, 5), (7, 15), (20, 25)], [(18, 17), (3, 4)]]
```

Comment: @Martijin per excellence, just what i was looking for $$$!

Comment: unfortunately am not able to up vote you cz i dont have 15 votes yet

Comment: you can mark his answer as been the one which solved your problem by clicking on the checkmark